# Show collapsed filters expanded by default

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

On this page (https://threadtheory.ca/blogs/sew-alongs) I'd like the "Filter +" button to be expanded by default... But I can't figure out how! The website is hosted through Shopify so it uses liquid as the template engine. Here's the section of code:

```
<div class="filters">
    {% if show_tags %}
    <a href="#" data-toggle-target=".tags.nav-row">{{ 'blogs.filtering.filter' | t }} <span class="state">+</span></a>
    {% endif %}
</div><!-- /.filters -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open in chrome -> right click filter element -> inspekt and look css styles. Then edit it in your project css file:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I did that earlier and it seems like it just changes "display: hidden" to "display: block", but the css class is this:

`.tags.nav-row {
  border-top: 1px solid $dividers-col;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $dividers-col;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}`

Do I just add display: block to that class?

Comment: No need to answer, it worked! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: no problem:) p.s. display dosn't have value "hidden":)